# Active indications of generated polyline API Google optimizations

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, navigation, logistics

I have a flutter app that reads a json created in Google optimization API, I draw the polyline and some markers in a Google maps in flutter, but I want to start navigation indications with the exact same polyline, I try to send the waypoints to External apps like Google maps, waze, etc but the route is not the same, i try also mapbox but the library that accept polylines not work only the other with waypoints, Google has Navigation SDK that works perfectly with optimization API, but is limited for specific users, how can I solve this, please give me some ideas, thanks

I try to start navigation indications with a route previously optimized, Actually I only draw the polyline and markers in a map inside my flutter app but I can't make a navigation indications with the same optimized route